# How do I attach 4 input pots to arduino?

Tags: analogread, potentiometer

I am making an arduino game and the requirement is that my arduino reads 4 analog values from the pots. I dont know whether I should use an external battery supply or the 5V from the duino' itself. I dont want my ICs to get fried or nothing happening at all.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really matter as long as the the voltage across your pots doesn't exceed the ARef or IORef voltage, which is usually equal to Vcc (3.3V or 5V) for the Arduino boards. It's best to use the 5V from your board. The ADC inputs are relatively high impedance so very little current flows through. Don't use very large value pots or you might not get the correct values from your analog inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Set up 4 pins as inputs. Wire the pots as voltage dividers (center wired to the input through a small-value resistor. One of the ends of the pot wired to +5V from your Arduino, and the other end wired to ground.)